# C#: get image path added to the imagelist

Tags: c#, imagelist

An image is added to the `imageList1` using this code:

```
imageList1.Images.Add("pic1", Image.FromFile("D:\\pic\\ha-i247.jpg"));
```

How can we get the full path of each image that added to the imagelist? (in this case: "D:\pic\ha-i247.jpg")

**INFO:** I know that the references can be kept using for example a list, I wondering about the capabilities of imageList itself.

Comment: Get it where? At what point? By clicking a button?

Comment: Your question is very unprecise. Describe what you are trying to do. We may simply answer "hold the image references outside the image list" if not.

Comment: I think the short answer is, No, image list does not retain a list of where the images came from. Once you've loaded it its just a picture in memory, it doesnt even remember if it came from file or something else

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't do that. Image list doesn't store where image came from. You can put path instead of name:

```
imageList1.Images.Add("D:\\pic\\ha-i247.jpg", Image.FromFile("D:\\pic\\ha-i247.jpg"));
```

And if you want to get it from there you can do something like this:

```
ImageList1.Images.Keys[0].ToString();
```

But it is not the best solution, better to store it outside the image list

Comment: Not sure why holding the references outside and unconnected would be better. The Keys collection is fine imo!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. The Images property is of type ImageCollection, which is a dictionary of Image objects. The Image object supports the Tag object property in which the programmer can store any information that want to.

Your code could read;

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(fileName);
img.Tag = fileName;
imageList.Images.Add('Img1',img);
```

You can get the file name by using

```
imageList.Images['Img1'].Tag;
```